# Exception: Expecting menu, got androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ContstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, exception, layout, android-resources

I hope you feel good.

So to my question, i am inflating a layout menu like you see at the bottom, but now I'll get an error while inflating the layout.

[image]

Here's the complete code of my layout and of the on ItemLongClick method. In addition I wanna create a long click on a Listitem and then let a popup came on the screen with different words like edit delete whatever.

***Is there anything wrong with my layout (ConstraintLayout)?***

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        PopupMenu p = new PopupMenu(ViewListContents.this, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = p.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, p.getMenu());
        p.show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

My popup_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout="@layout/include"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/order_takeout"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:onClick="doTakeOut"
        android:title="@string/delete"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/order_eat_in"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:onClick="doEatIn"
        android:title="@string/edit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/order_takeout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***I would like to thank you in advance for any feedback***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a menu resource file, you can't have a layout resource file. Change the location of your XML file to the menu resource directory. If You don't have a menu resource directory, create it and place your XML file(pop_layout.xml) there.Also, you can't have a constraint layout in a menu resource file.ViewGroups are only for layout resource files,not for menu resource files.

Menu resporce files look like this :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@+id/mail"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_mail"
   android:title="@string/mail" />
    <item android:id="@+id/upload"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_upload"
    android:title="@string/upload"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:title="@string/share" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it works exactly as I want! I just had to change these things:

`</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>` to `<menu>`

and in my onItemLongClick Method:

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, p.getMenu());` to `inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_layout, p.getMenu());`

and i removed some named stuff in my items and of course the constraints.

Comment: Probably you can give my Question an upvote then will another guy see it and it helps him to get the solution.